# Unable to change alpha during playmode

Tags: unity-game-engine

So my problem is that when I go into playmode and try to change the alpha color value of an object, it does not change.

[image]

It should show a bar under the color when I change the alpha value, like this:

[image]

Comment: Well I pulled up a project, ran it, and I could change the alpha during runtime, and the bar that indicates alpha also changed.

Comment: Do you set this color via any script or do you maybe have any `Animator` component that sets this value?

Answer (score 0):

So I just solved this by reinstalling Unity. I think Unity might've not been installed properly, because now it works fine.